# Issue with (not set) fields inside Google Analytics on various reports

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

One month ago on web site, [www.cashflowtallinn.ee](http://www.cashflowtallinn.ee) I noticed an issue related to Google Analytics, which is representing as large amount (over 80% of our traffic) viewed by Google as (not set).

**This is causing different issues, such as:**

- If we want to see what pages users mostly visit, biggest percentage is (not set)
- If we want to see default languages, biggest percentage is (not set)
- If we want to see traffic sources, mostly it's viewed as Direct traffic, but this is not true, since most of our traffic is Social networks.

**I tried to resolve issue:**

- Installed Google Tag Assistant, but it reports all is good.
- Examined `<head>` section and found out that web site has several `<title>` instances, could this cause issues?
- Found this from Google Support https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2820717?hl=en
- Fount this, but couldn't find solution http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/06/25/11-places-google-analytics-not-set/

Any ideas how to handle this (and issues like this one) ?

There is always a possibility to turn of all plugins and switch back to default theme (since it's WordPress web site), but I would like to test this on live site, and make it work live, so switching off plugins and changing theme is actually not a good idea.

All best,

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your GA code is outside of head tag.

1. I'd consider fixing the location GA code (inside head tag)
2. you have 2 same GA codes installed (bad practice)

Images attached.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J71Fp.png)